# Trigger to update timestamp if new field value != old field value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm trying to update a field called `LastUpdate` with a timestamp whenever either one of 2 other fields are changed to a value that's different from the original value.  Those two columns are `LoadDate` and `CompleteDate`.  The trigger I have works, but since I'm updating the row each time I run my process, regardless of whether the date changes, its updating the timestamp.  I need to compare to see if the old `LoadDate` is different from the new `LoadDate`, or if the old `CompleteDate` is different from the new `CompleteDate`.  Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER time_stamp 
ON my_table
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @LoadDate datetime, @CompleteDate datetime
    SELECT @LoadDate = LoadDate, @CompleteDate = CompleteDate FROM my_table

    UPDATE my_table 
    SET LastUpdate = GETDATE()
    WHERE LoadDate = @LoadDate
    AND CompleteDate = @CompleteDate 
END
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  You can use the to compare the _before_ and _after_ values and update the correct rows. [This](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/) provides an introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need one statement in your trigger. Something like this ought to do:

```
update MT
  set LastUpdate = GetDate()
  from My_Table as MT inner join
    -- Inner join with   inserted   to pick up only those rows inserted or updated.
    inserted as i on i.YourIdColumn = MT.YourIdColumn left outer join
    -- Left outer join with   deleted   to pick up the "before" values if this is an UPDATE.
    deleted as d on d.YourIdColumn = MT.YourIdColumn
  where
    -- LoadDate has changed or this is an INSERT.
    ( i.LoadDate <> d.LoadDate or d.LoadDate is NULL ) or
    -- CompleteDate has changed or this is an INSERT.
    ( i.CompleteDate <> d.CompleteDate or d.CompleteDate is NULL )
```

Note that this is performing a set operation. An INSERT or UPDATE that affects multiple rows will cause the trigger to fire *once* and process all of the affected rows.